# kotlin spring inject map from application.properties

Tags: spring, kotlin

I need to inject the **Map<String, String>** from the **application.properties** file in key-value format using Spring annotation **@Value** in **Kotlin**.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject map from property file as below

```
example.map={key1:'value1',key2:'value2'}
```

Inject in Kotlin

```
@Value("#{\${example.map}}")
val myMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf()
```